# Page quickly reformats itself mostly in Chrome

Tags: html, css, webkit

After some changes to our site, we are seeing that when certain pages are loaded, the page quickly changes width. This occurs every time on webkit browsers Chrome and Safair, but only rarely on some other browsers.

I have not been able to produce the effect at all on Firefox on Windows, Firefox on Mac, nor IE9 and IE11. It seems to rarely occur on IE8 and IE10. I have not found a pattern yet that causes it to appear on IE8 and IE10.

To understand what might be causing this, it would be good to know if certain styling attributes take an initial value while the page is loading but them assume some other value by the time the page is fully loaded. This could explain what is happening.

I should add that this problem developed after some changes which "should" not have caused this issue. Basically having to do with adding URL rewriting to eliminate duplicate pages. Clearly some side effect is operative.

At the moment we only have the code on development servers, so it would not be that easy to actually see it right now, although that is the obvious first question from a responder. So at this point, the question is more "what generically causes pages to reformat under Webkit."

UPDATE: the problem seems to be traced to Google Translate. When I remove that from the page, the problem goes away. Put it back; problem comes back.

Oddly, it mostly impacts Chrome! IE10 and 11 are exempt, and with even earlier IE versions the problem is much less.

I can readily demonstrate the temporary widening of the page just by reloading the page.

I experimented with trying to put the div containing the translate div instead a container div and setting some attributes on that. So far I have not found something that mitigates the problem.

We have suppressed Google Translate recently because it started adding other junk to the bottom of the page. That other junk is gone but we will continue to suppress it due to this new jumpiness.

I believe there is some clever way to contain the issue, but have no more time for it.

Comment: `<img />`s that don't have `width` and `height` attributes set will suddenly push the page around once they do load, but that should happen in all browsers, depending on the speed of downloading. Is there styling being assigned to certain elements using JS, or content being populated via JS? That could affect it too.

Comment: Our coding standards require width and height on all img tags. It is possible something has escaped us, and is worth looking for. Checking though shows that is not a problem.

Comment: I might have found the culprit. It seems to be a side effect of having Google Translate enabled for some of our websites. When the widget loads, it causes the page width to vary. As we are not using this on our production site, it should be be a problem. After further confirmation, I will "answer my own question" with this result.

Comment: Updating question with further information about Google Translate as the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have confirmed that the issue is definitely caused by Google Translate being on the page.